# What's difference between ptr=&n and ptr = (int*)malloc(4)for my code?

Tags: pointers, malloc

Considerung this example code:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>

        int main(void){
        int i=0,n;
        int*ptr;                  /*this program attempts to prompt user to keep entering integer 
                                values untill he gives 9 as input */
        //ptr=&n;
        ptr = (int*)malloc(4);
        for(i=0;;i++)
        {
           scanf("%d",ptr+i);
           if(*(ptr+i)==9)
           return 0;
        }
        return 0;
        }
```

The above code works well by prompting the user to keep entering integers until he enters 9.
But if I write

```
    ptr=&n;
```

instead of

```
    ptr = (int*)malloc(4);
```

it doesn't works properly.
Please clarify why one works while the other doesn't, as each time `ptr` is a pointer storing addresses of memory blocks that store integral values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `ptr=&n;` you take the address of an existing variable.
You would be able to access the variable directly and you can access it via the pointer.

With `ptr = (int*)malloc(4);` you take the address of a newly allocated pice of memory. Assuming that `sizeof(int)==4` in your environment here.
You can only access it via the pointer.

In both cases your loop, from the second interation (when `>0`) accesses memory you are not allowed to access.

If you observe a difference, e.g. that the code seems to work with the second version, but not with the first, then the explanation is that you got lucky, or unlucky, depending on your philosophy on how and when you want to notice errors.